# Weird incident with DownloadStringAsync

Tags: wpf

I'm using the following code to download the source code of an HTML page

```
String search = $"<search url>";
String result = "";
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
     var searchURL = new Uri(search);
     wc.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
     {
         result = e.Result;
     };
     wc.DownloadStringAsync(searchURL);
}
return result.Trim();
```

This exists in a static method

```
public static Scrape(String arg)
```

of a class Scraper.
However, when I do

```
txtResult.Text = Scraper.Scrape(arg);
```

in the code behing of a form, nothing appears. Using breakpoints, I see that e.Result indeed contains the expected data, but something happens and the data is "lost" in the way. Anyone has any idea what I'm missing;

Comment: Better use [HttpClient.GetStringAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh551746(v=vs.118).aspx) because it can be awaited. Right now you are disposing the WebClient and return from the method immediately after starting the download.

Comment: Indeed, return happens before completion! (duh!). Any sample on HttpClient?

Comment: `var result = await new HttpClient().GetStringAsync(search);` returns the downloaded content as string without blocking the UI. The method that makes the call has to be declared as `async`.

Comment: I'm trying that too
Update : It works, too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the download is asynchronous it hasn't updated the value of result before you reach the line return "result.Trim()" as a result you are returning the empty string.

You need to wait for WC to complete, if you use the task method then accessing the result property will cause you to wait for the response.

```
String search = $"<search url>";
String result = "";
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
     var searchURL = new Uri(search);
     result = wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(searchURL).Result;
}
return result.Trim();
```

However if you do this in the current method as it stands you will end up hanging your UI as the wait happens on the foreground thread.

You can move the update to the background by changing your call to use a task with a continuation.

Instead of

```
txtResult.Text = Scraper.Scrape(arg);
```

Add a using `using System.Threading.Tasks;`

then you can use the line

```
Task.Run(() => Scraper.Scrape(arg))
    .ContinueWith(t => txtResult.Text = t.Result,
                  TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

You may also want to precede this with a line `txtResult.Text = "Please Wait Fetching....";`

Comment: This is a simple fix and doesn't deal with cancelling the task or exceptions occurring during the fetch (which can be handled in ContinueWith)

Comment: And it works! Canceling the fetch is not a concern right now! Thanks!